# Creating global aspects in postsharp

Tags: postsharp, aop

I am looking for a way in which to all aspects to run on methods in many places in my project, without having to manually add in the attribute tag to each method or class.

My entire solution holds around 20 separate projects.  One of which I have created called myname.space.Attributes which holds my attribute declarations, as well as a file called GlobalAspects which has the following:

```
using PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics;
using PostSharp.Extensibility;
using myname.space.Attributes;

// This file contains registration of aspects that are applied to several classes of this project.
[assembly: TraceLoggingAttribute(AttributeTargetTypes = "myname.space.Controllers.*", 
                            AttributeTargetTypeAttributes = MulticastAttributes.AnyVisibility, 
                            AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.AnyVisibility)
]

[assembly: TraceLoggingAttribute(AttributeTargetTypes = "myname.space.Repositories.*",
                            AttributeTargetTypeAttributes = MulticastAttributes.AnyVisibility,
                            AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.AnyVisibility)
]
```

The goal of this was to add my TraceLoggingAttribute to all the methods held within these other 2 projects, Controllers and Repositories.

I have set up these 2 other projects to reference the Attributes project, and the attribute works perfectly fine if I put the [TraceLoggingAttribute] tag on the classes and methods within the Controller and Repositories projects.

Is there a way in which I can set up my GlobalAspects.cs to work in the way I am looking for? Please ask question if I have not explained the issue well enough here

For interest, the TraceLoggingAttribute is defined as:

```
namespace myname.space.Attributes
{
    [MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method, TargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Instance)]
    [Serializable]
    public class TraceLoggingAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can only apply attributes to currently compiled assembly (or to calls to other assemblies through TargetAssembly property but that also affects only currently compiled assembly).

I think that the easiest solution would be to link GlobalAspects.cs into all projects that you want to be affected by it. This should work as you expect and not cause any problems.

Hope that helps.

Comment: so do you mean to have essentially a GlobalAspects,cs in each project?